# Anatomically Correct Argonian

Tags: internal-consistency, creature-design, evolution

Enter the [Argonian](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Argonian): a *(really)* ugly sentient human-like lizard. Although almost no one plays as this race on their Skyrim playthroughs, they have some pretty astounding capabilities; they are masters of guerilla warfare, can breathe underwater, can communicate in a spoken language, and have lifespans similar to those of humans.

What evolution could support the existence of such creatures? Could the Argonians even exist, biologically speaking?

[image]

This question is part of the [Anatomically Correct Series](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/anatomically-correct-series/2798#2798).

Comment: Can you think of any good reason why they _wouldn't_ exist?

Comment: @AndreiROM Earth reptiles aren't really known for their bipedal stance and higher intellegence.

Comment: @tres-2b - sure, but neither are bipedal, sapient cats. However, the concept of bipedal beings is solid. Sapience exists. It's within the realm of possibility that an Argonian race could evolve somewhere, under the right evolutionary constraints - there's no one thing about Argonians that screams "no, this is impossible". They didn't evolve on Earth, clearly, but they might _somewhere_.

Comment: @AndreiROM hence why the question is valid

Comment: @tres-2b - I never said it was invalid, I'm simply pointing out that the answer is obviously "Yes, they could theoretically exist".

Comment: @AndreiROM good point, the question cold be worded better by the OP

Comment: `they have some pretty astounding capabilities; they (...) can communicate in a spoken language` I was going to point that this is not an astounding capability, but then I remembered a lot of people with whom I have to deal on a daily basis and yeah, that seems like a rare skill to me.

Comment: Also, maybe in our world those guys could have evolved from velociraptors or other theropod, had they not been killed off millions of years ago.

Comment: Just from looking at the picture, breathing underwater seems unlikely as nostrils of that size and shape would not be conducive to pulling in and expelling large volumes of water. It looks more like this creature could hold its breath for long periods of time (unless of course there are organs for underwater breathing which are not pictured).

Comment: In general I would be careful trying to apply Scientifiic principles to any fantasy realm, but I would be especially careful with the Elder Scrolls. Physics, Biology, and Chemistry as we understand not only do not exist but are replaced with magic/ethereal based alternatives. This is especially true for the Argonians. They are that form because the entity that they come from( called the Hist) is powerful and wills it that way. Trying to make sense of with the rules of our world is fruitless.

Comment: @knowads -- this is more a question of "are the *traits* manifested by the Argonians plausible in the context of RL biology and evolution?"  (It's also useful because lizardfolk are a common fantasy trope, and the Argonians are a well-understood proxy for that trope.)  Or, "how could a deity put the pieces and parameters in place to make such a race pop out of the evolutionary apparatus we know about?"

Answer (score 7):

Please, for the love of all that is reality-based, do not give your Argonian maids boobs. If they are reptilian at all there is no plausible reason for this. It's [a mammalian characteristic](https://www.quora.com/Do-any-snakes-nurse-their-young).

Ladies should have different markings, a lack of frills or something else if you crave differentiation.

There should be no nipples on either gender.

As for plausibility, they just need to evolve hands with an opposable thumb and there are a lot of reptiles that have hands close to this. And they would need to stand upright. There were dinosaurs that did stand on their hind legs, so I would opt for branching out from that. They would also need a stable environment as far as temperature is concerned, as they can't regulate their body temperature as well as mammals can. Dressing for warmth just won't cut it.

Comment: I almost spit my drink on my screen girl! Your sense of humor is wicked!

Comment: Also, if I EVER see scales on a woman's boobs...I'm GONE!

Comment: @Inquisitive Yeah... lizard tits should not be a thing. And yet. Bethesda has given us so much, but this is one gift I would definitely return.

Answer (score 0):

I think dinosaurs could have evolved to human intelligence if they had survived extinction events. **I think evolution thrives on hardship**. The smaller dinosaurs would have had to evolve intelligence in order to survive the big boys. It's what explains the extremely nasty dispositions of Hippos. Their attitudes evolved as such to help them survive certain predators.

Nature is so dynamic, I'm certain it's at least possible dinosaurs could have evolved to human intelligence.

Comment: But why would these dinosaurs become bipedal, and how would they outcompete more intelligent creatures?

Comment: @IchthysKing a lot of dinosaurs were already bipedal, and if we define intelligence as the ability to learn things and practice them while also understanding abstract things then yeah.... Dinosaurs were pretty darn intelligent. For example in my story dinosaurs never went extinct and the iguanodon took the evolutionary niche of adaptable intelligent species. They have all the tools needed to evolve human like sapience 1)Tool use 2) sociality 3) reason to develop tools

Answer (score 0):

Argonians could have evolved from aquatic reptiliomorphs that became hematophagous. To protect their gills, they would evolve a velum like a lamprey. With this, they could seal their gills and leave the water. They may evolve to become tree-dwellers, and evolve convergently with humans until they become the Argonians.